# gsutil got an syntax error with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

In my Case, I want to upload all of pdf file to google cloud storage.

So I use google-sdk with pytho subprocess for practice instead of "google.cloud.storage API".

But there is an error below:

**Code:**

```
from subprocess import Popen

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    print(f'$>: {command}')
    process = Popen(command,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    executable='/bin/bash',
                    shell=True)

    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    print(proc_stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Exec Function**:

```
command = "gsutil -m cp -r ./source/*(.pdf|.PDF) gs://<bucket_name>"
subprocess_cmd(command)
```

**Error**:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `gsutil -m cp -r ./source/*(.pdf|.PDF) gs://<bucket_name>'
```

Comment: It's not possible to run a command with `/*(.pdf|.PDF)`, the command will not work properly. I have tried to replicate it on my side and I couldn't use it as well. Considering that, the supported way of using GCS with Python is to use the Google Cloud Client Library for Python and not running the gsutil. Could you please clarify why you are not using it?

Comment: But `gsutil -m cp -r ./source/*(.pdf|.PDF) gs://<bucket_name>` is work on Terminal

Comment: Hi @EEEEH it might work, but it's not supported - probably works because `gsutil` is based in Unix environment - and might not work properly. In addition to that, could you please clarify why not using the Google Cloud Client Library for Python instead of Python  Subprocess?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel, I didn't use client library because that I just want to know subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this line instead:

```
command = "gsutil -m cp -r ./source/{*.pdf,*.PDF} gs://<bucket_name>"
```

See the `{ } (curly brackets)` section in [this document](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) about `bash` wildcards. You can also see [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) about `gsutil` wildcards.